# Google Protobuf ByteString vs. Byte[]

Tags: java, string, arrays, protocol-buffers

I am working with google protobuf in Java. 
I see that it is possible to serialize a protobuf message to String, byte[], ByteString, etc:
(Source: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageLite)

I don't know what a ByteString is. I got the following definition from the the protobuf API documentation (source: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/ByteString):
"Immutable sequence of bytes. Substring is supported by sharing the reference to the immutable underlying bytes, as with String."

It is not clear to me how a ByteString is different from a String or byte[].
Can somebody please explain?
Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can think of `ByteString` as an immutable byte array. That's pretty much it. It's a `byte[]` which you can use in a protobuf. Protobuf does not let you use Java arrays because they're mutable.

`ByteString` exists because `String` is not suitable for representing arbitrary sequences of bytes. `String` is specifically for character data.

> The protobuf MessageLite Interface provides toByteArray() and toByteString() methods. If ByteString is an immutable byte[], would the byte representation of a message represented by both ByteString and byte[] be the same?

Sort of. If you call `toByteArray()` you'll get the same value as if you were to call `toByteString().toByteArray()`. Compare the implementation of the two methods, in `AbstractMessageLite`:

```
public ByteString toByteString() {
  try {
    final ByteString.CodedBuilder out =
      ByteString.newCodedBuilder(getSerializedSize());
    writeTo(out.getCodedOutput());
    return out.build();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(
      "Serializing to a ByteString threw an IOException (should " +
      "never happen).", e);
  }
}

public byte[] toByteArray() {
  try {
    final byte[] result = new byte[getSerializedSize()];
    final CodedOutputStream output = CodedOutputStream.newInstance(result);
    writeTo(output);
    output.checkNoSpaceLeft();
    return result;
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(
      "Serializing to a byte array threw an IOException " +
      "(should never happen).", e);
  }
}
```

Comment: The protobuf MessageLite Interface provides toByteArray() and toByteString() methods. If ByteString is an immutable byte[], would the byte representation of a message represented by both ByteString and byte[] be the same?

Comment: where is `writeTo` defined?

Comment: @LeiYang it's [declared on the `MessageLite` interface](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageLite) and the implementations are part of each generated protobuf class.

Answer (score 10):

A `ByteString` gives you the ability to perform more operations on the underlying data without having to copy the data into a new structure.  For instance, if you wanted to provide a subset of `bytes` in a `byte[]` to another method, you would need to supply it with a start index and an end index.  You can also concatenate `ByteStrings` without having to create a new data structure and manually copy the data.

However, with a `ByteString` you can give the method a subset of that data without the method knowing anything about the underlying storage.  Just like a a substring of a normal String.

A String is for representing text and is *not* a good way to store binary data (as not all binary data has a textual equivalent unless you encode it in a manner that does: e.g. hex or Base64).