# why protobuf use byte[] for bytes in golang but use string/ByteString for bytes in other language?

Tags: java, go, protocol-buffers

as specified here https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#scalar

protobuf use byte[] for bytes in golang but use string/ByteString for bytes in other language, why the difference ?

as explained by @Volker , string is not suitalbe to hold arbitrary []byte.

then why pb is using string/ByteString for bytes in all other language except go ?

Comment: Actually string is _suitable_ to hold arbitrary bytes, its just not really elegant and what strings are.

Answer (score 1):

- []byte is natural for streams of bytes
- strings in Go are not byte streams but immutable strings
- strings in Go *should* be UTF-8 encoded, at least that's what for-ranging over them assumes, using a non-UTF-8 byte stream in a string is possible but kinda inelegant.
- there is no ByteString type in Go. Well, actually there is: []byte.

Comment: but still a little bit confused

1.  []byte is natural for streams of bytes
i totally agree with you on this.  but why pb use string/ByteString for bytes instead of using byte[] directly.  i read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018411/google-protobuf-bytestring-vs-byte, but it didn't explain why string instead of byte[].

Comment: strings in Go should be UTF-8 encoded, at least that's what for-ranging over them assumes

string in other language, like java s also bind to charset , and not suitable to hold arbitrary byte[]

Comment: @MichaelShy there is a difference between Java and Go. There is no ByteString in Go. The question why _Java_ uses ByteString and not []byte (Java) is not related to Go. Basically there is nothing to see or know here. In Go it's []byte.

Comment: thank you anyway,  your answer do help me understanding this better ; )